# Is there a way to programmatically add register methods to a REST web service without using annotations?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Is there any REST framework that supports programmatically addition of methods? I don't want to use annotations. I want to do something like this:

```
RestServer server = new RestServer("http://localhost:5678");
server.registerOperation("/ping","com.mypackage.service.Ping","methodName","GET");
server.registerOperation("/add/{number}/{number}","com.mypackage.service.Math","sum","POST");
server.start();
```

Comment: I'm just curious, why not use annotations?  You want to dynamically add them in a config file or something?

Comment: yep. the configuration will be dynamically added

Answer (score 0):

There is! It's called [compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki), but you're going to have to learn [clojure](http://clojure.org) first.

Comment: there  must be something for java